# what is the suitable alternative for content place holder in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

'm self learning wpf. i've designed a form with 2 header panels containing different menu buttons and the rest is blank.

now i want to display the click events [like a gridview or a listview] on the remaining empty section of the form like as in web application we can use a content place holder to display click events...problem is i can't find a suitable option for this...[i dn't like mdi form's very much]..so any suggestion will be helpful...my code thus far is as follows,[ all the clickevents are there on my cs page and works fine so not included]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.EFSHome"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EFSHome" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Cornsilk" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cornsilk" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="grid0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="234*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="everest.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        </Image>
        <Grid Name="grid1" Margin="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="panel1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3">

                <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" Content="RMS Entry" Name="btn_RMS_Entry" 
                        ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" Click="btn_RMS_Entry_Click">
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Background="Transparent">
                            <MenuItem Header="Shipment"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Order"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="LC"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="BL"/>                            
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" Content="RMS Payment" Name="btn_RMS_P"></Button>

            </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid Name="grid2" Margin="3,30,0,7">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="panel3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,0,5" Height="35">

                    <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"  Content="Edit" Name="btn_Edit" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"  Content="emp_list" Name="btn_Emp"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"  Content="Exit" Name="btn_Exit" Click="btn_Exit_Click" />

                </StackPanel>
               </Grid>            
            </Grid>                    
        </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display the click events"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Xaml you shared, it's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  However, I have simplified your layout to the following:

```
<Window x:Class="DisplayClickEventsResponse.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EFSHome" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cornsilk" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="RMS Entry"></Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="RMS Payment"></Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Edit"></Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Emp_list"></Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Exit"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="theListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

In the code behind, the Button_Click handler looks like the following:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    theListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("The button {0} was clicked", ((Button)sender).Content));
}
```

I chose to use the same Click event handler for each button, for simplicity.  The handler simply formats a string that is added as an item to the ListBox.  I removed the MyBorderStyle style since the layout contains no Borders.  I used a simpler DockPanel in order to have the buttons at the top (using a StackPanel) and used a ListBox (taking up the remaining space) to display the Click events.

I hope this helps.